# How do I work off two Mac Minis?

Tags: mac-mini

I have one Mac Mini (1 TB) and I am about out of space. Buying a new with 2T is some $2500-out of my budget. I can just muster to buy another 1 TB...

Is there a way that I can do my work (on one screen, with one keyboard) accessing two / both Mac Mini's?

(For example, what takes up most on my computer is images, so I was thinking if I put all images on one Mac Mini...)

Thank you for any help - most appreciated. PS> Please know I am no techie-person.

Comment: will this work for you https://www.macworld.com/article/2142073/connecting-two-macs-using-thunderbolt.html

Comment: Thank you very much! It sure looks promising. Talking about IP addresses... Does this work over Internet connection? I am not so attached to that everything is lightning-fast at all; I do live in remote Alaska and have outings / slow connection compared to people in the rest of the country.

Comment: Why not just upgrade the drive in the first Mac mini?  It's cheaper and you'll get exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: You could share a screen over internet (remote login) but connecting to the disk is likely going to be too slow to be useful. Within the same network (both computers plugged into the same router) you should be fine. However, since you are talking Minis, why not a KVM switch? That's the default answer for "how do I use one set of peripherals with two computers".